How to incorporate data cleansing into trained model
If I cleanse the data and impute median value into NaN values, am I supposed to somehow incorporate this into my model that will be used on the test data?  In other words, doesn't my test data need to be cleansed and imputed as well, or will the training take care of this?
I want to say it needs to be incorporated, because otherwise the NaN values break the model, plus any skewness wouldn't have been addressed.
In particular:
Replace NaN with median:
data = data.fillna(data.median())

Deal with skewness using Quantile Transformation to follow a normal distribution for each feature (the following is just for one).
qualtile_transformer = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal', random_state=0')
data['feat_0'] = quantile_transformer.fit_transform(data['feat_0'].values.reshape(-1,1)).flatten()

Model:
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linear_regr = LinearRegression()
linear_regr.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)

Prediction:
# make prediction using the testing set
Ypred = linear_regr.predict(Xtest)

So, ultimately, if I were to take my model and use it on a similar but different data, how can I be sure it doesn't fail and the NaNs and Quantile transformation will be taken care of with the new data before the prediction is implemented so it won't fail?

Yes, you need to preprocess/prepare your validation/test data as well. Sklearn makes this very simple for you with pipelines.
Basically, every data transformer and model can be part of a pipeline.
If there sklearn has not the right data transformer for your use case, it is also very simple to write your own one.
To give you a little demonstration (this works as is):
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

RANDOM_STATE = 0

# define all your preprocessing steps
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    # fill nan with median
    SimpleImputer(missing_values=pd.NA, strategy="median"), 
    QuantileTransformer(output_distribution="normal", random_state=RANDOM_STATE,),
    # regression model
    LinearRegression(),
)

# load some toy dataset for demonstration
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

# split into training and test dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X,
    y,
    test_size=0.3,
    random_state=RANDOM_STATE,
)

# fit pipeline on train data
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# now only use .score, .predict etc.
train_score = pipeline.score(X_train, y_train)
test_score = pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)

print(f'Train: {train_score:.2f}, Test: {test_score:.2f}')
# Train: 0.51, Test: 0.38

The important part about pipelines lies in the methods you call. The same method will be sequentially called on all steps in the pipeline. So you fit your model with the training data. Afterward, you only call the score or predict method. If you use fit again, you would overwrite the parameters learned from the first-pass.
